# Remote desktop connection to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, password-protection, rdp

I have created a new free-tier windows 2019 EC2 instance in my default VPC, the new EC2 has a public IP, and the security group allows the traffic from anywhere and the RDP protocol is already configured to be ready on port 3389.

I have spent two days now with no luck connecting to this instance from windows remote desktop.

I have tried to ping the ec2 from my machine but no luck.

telnet from my machine to the ec2 working perfectly.
I have disabled the windows firewall.

remote desktop sometimes asks me to enter the password and sometimes doesn't ask at all.

**** when I changed my wifi network, I do the remote desktop connection and I can access the ec2 instance.

Any help in this.

Comment: Have a look here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html#connect-rdp

Comment: Ping is not a good test of RDP because it requires additional network configurations. Was the instance launched in a **public subnet** (defined as having a Route Table entry that points to an Internet Gateway)? When you say "no luck", can you please provide more information? For example, what is the error message? Does it fail immediately, or take some time before it fails?

Comment: "when I changed my wifi network" - this seems that you have issue on your side, not AWS side. Maybe you have some firewalls in place or some other issues with the wifi blocking access to aws.

Comment: I agree with @Marcin, the trouble should be in your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as you have. In my case, The internet service provider blocked the SSH connection(PORT). though our security group allows to all we can't connect our instance.

Take this to them and get it fixed:).

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to setup your inbound rules on the security group.

- Go to **Instances** and find the value for the column: **Security Group Name**
- Then under **Network and Security** go to **Security groups**.
- Click on the **Security group ID** that has the matching Security Group Name you looked up.
- In the inbound rules you need to make sure you add yours and modify it until it looks like this:

  - Type: RDP Protocol:
  - TCP Port: 3389
  - Source: 0.0.0.0/0
  - Description: open to the world to test only

Better would be to use a source that you know you are coming from, but you'll need to change it if your IP changes.

https://www.whatismyip.com/

if your IP is 17.18.19.20,

then enter 17.18.19.20/32

Answer (score 1):

I have a windows machine in EC2 which works, with the security groups set up as follows:

- Inbound RDP, TCP port 3389 from 0.0.0.0/0
- Inbound All ICMP v4 from 0.0.0.0/0 <- This is necessary to ping the machine
- Outbound All traffic, All protocols, all ports to 0.0.0.0/0
- Outbound ALL traffic, All protocols, all ports to ::/0

A few more hints:

- If you restarted the machine and haven't attached an elastic IP, the public IP address will have changed
- You can try telnetting to the RDP port 3389
- Run the reachability analyzer tool in the VPC management console
- You can try connecting via a different computer or a different connection, e.g. a personal hotspot to rule out firewall issues on your side

Update:

RDP is a quite ressource-intensive protocol compared to e.g. ssh or telnet. You haven't specified if you are trying this from a home or corporate network. Could the quality of your internet connection be a problem? Comparing to e.g. a public or private hotspot might help.

Last but not least, you say it worked when you "changed your wifi network" - I'm not quite sure what to make of that statement. Did you change the configuration? Did you change TO your wifi from a wired network?

If you are in a high-density area, Wifi networks can strangle each other. If you always were wireless, try wired. If your wireless works better than your wired, check the cables for kinks and tears.

Colleagues of mine once spent an hour trying to find out why a mainboard would always go into flash mode, until I suggested unplugging the keyboard - it was a stuck F10 key. Bottom line: try to think of the factors you've so far overlooked.

Comment: What I mean by "changed your wifi network" is the following: when I was using wifi#1 which belongs to ISP#1 ==> I can't remote desktop. once I changed the ISP#2 and connected to wifi #2 remote desktop works perfectly.

Comment: @ManKeer so what you did is basically what I meant by trying a personal hotspot or something. The fact that it did work, plus the fact that you don't have anything crazy in your security groups apparently, IMO gives a 95% chance there's either a firewall or a routing problem in what you referred to as wifi#1. The remaining 5% is what some sort of weird configuration issue on your machine, ISP#1 or your cloud would add up to IMO. If you have control over your router, you can check that, if you don't it's time to hand this over to your IT department.